# Getting the value of a dynamically created input

Tags: php, jquery

I have following jquery script which load a form into a div "blankform"

```
jQuery('#metentry').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    // getting data from form to variables
    var date = jQuery('#stddate').val();
    var kgsunit = jQuery('#unit').val();
    var kgsshift = jQuery('#shift').val();

    //sending data to script
    jQuery.post("get_blank_form.php", {
        "date": jQuery('#stddate').val(), 
        'unit': kgsunit,
        'shift': kgsshift, 
    }, function(data) {      
        //loading a form to the div blankform
        jQuery('#blankform').html(data);
    });
```

get_blank_form.php contains following code

```
<?php
    echo'<form id="shiftentry" name="shiftentry" >';
    echo "Date:<input id=shiftdate value='".$date."'/>"; 
    echo "Unit:<input id=shiftdate value='".$unit."'/>";
    echo "Shift:<input id=shiftdate value='".$shift."'/><br/>";
    echo "<table><tr><th>No</th><th>Ele</th><th>Location</th><th>Dose Rate (mGy/h)</th><th> Tritium (DAC)</th>  <th>Part (DAC)</th> <th>Iodine (DAC)</th><th>   Surface Cont. (Bq/cm2) </th></tr>";

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result_sec))
    { 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".++$rc."</td>";
        echo "<td><input size='5' id='".$row2['elevation']."' value='".$row2['elevation']."' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input id='".$row2['loc_id']."' value='".$row2['location']."' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input size='5' id='dose".$rc."'  value='".$row2['radn_level']."'/></td>";
        echo "<td><input size='5' id='h3".$rc."' value='0' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input size='5' id='part".$rc."' value='0' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input size='5' id='iod".$rc."' value='0' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input size='5' id='cont".$rc."' value='0' /></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo " </table>";
    echo '<div align="center">';
    echo '<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" width="30" />';
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

this will create a form which will have input like `id1`, `id2` ... `id25`, `dose1`, `dose2` ... `dose25` and so on.

I want to read the values of these input boxes. Normal method like `var loc1 = $("#id1").val();` is not working since these elements are dynamically created.

Even the submit button clicking even is also not triggered.

the script below do not produce any output.

```
jQuery('#shiftentry').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    alert("Submitted");
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: e.preventDefault(); make the submit event from being executed.

Comment: yes, i will use an ajax request inside this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Form DOM is dynamically created after Ajax Call, You can use .on ?

like:

```
$(document).on('submit' , '#shiftentry' , function(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); 
 alert("Submitted");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the submit button, you can trigger it using

```
$('#submit_id').on('click', function(){
    $('#shiftentry').send(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        alert("Submitted");
    );
})
```

as for getting the values using.

```
$('#id1').val()
```

this should just work just fine but remember that some characters are not permitted in id field such as [, ], . etc..  if you cant avoid this special characters in your id field you can use.

```
$('input[name="value"]').val();
```

to get the value of your fields.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for event handling as the form is created using ajax call and added later.

As it's added later, it will not be bound to `submit` event handler that you had specified. To bind it with the handler you need to use `on()` from jQuery.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#shiftentry', function() {
    //Your code
});
```